# Proxying play application

Tags: apache, proxy, playframework, playframework-2.1

On my server, I have installed *Apache HTTP*, *Tomcat* and need to deploy my *Play* application.

The configuration of my *Apache HTTP* server that I had and worked was this:

At the end of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I had whose lines that proxied all incomming requests to tomcat. And it was good.

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

Now, because I need to deploy my *Play* application also, I put the following before the above last two lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPass  /excluded !
    ProxyPass /my_play_app http://localhost:9000/my_play_app
    ProxyPassReverse /my_play_app http://localhost:9000/my_play_app
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when I try to access the play application with this configuration, it doesn't respond. Can you give me some hints on how to solve my issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apache has been amazing over the years for the things it does well, but I've found for serving static assets and reverse proxying to separate running HTTP services, such as Play applications, nginx is light, fast and solid.

The nginx config I use for Play is similar to:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    # Without this, Play serves the assets from within it's bundled jar. That's
    # fine and works but seems unnecessary when nginx can serve the files directly.
    location /assets {
        alias /app/live/my-play-app-here/active/public;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312969/963195) has some more detail.